# How to add Pagination in Fluent UI Detaillist using react

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, pagination, fluent-ui

I have created the sample by using this link
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist

Now I want to add Pagination in the grid. Please let me know the steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `import { Pagination } from '@uifabric/experiments';`

```
  <Pagination
        selectedPageIndex={page}
        pageCount={pageCount}
        onPageChange={onPageChange}
        format
        firstPageIconProps={{ iconName: 'DoubleChevronLeft' }}
        previousPageIconProps={{ iconName: 'ChevronLeft' }}
        nextPageIconProps={{ iconName: 'ChevronRight' }}
        lastPageIconProps={{ iconName: 'DoubleChevronRight' }}
    />
```

Comment: Except the path should be `'@fluentui/react-experiments/lib/Pagination'` and the package is named @fluentui/react-experiments

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work with v9 as the package is trying to use font icons for the buttons.  It might be better to copy the source and reimplement it with your own icon buttons:  https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/tree/master/packages/react-experiments/src/components/Pagination